# I want to refresh a page after a function is executed?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function theFinale()
{ document.getElementById("pop2").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("pop3").style.display = 'none';


        document.getElementById("pop4").style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('pop4').style.position = "absolute";
         document.getElementById('pop4').style.top = '250px';
        document.getElementById('pop4').style.left = '250px';
        setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('pop4').className = 'waa';
        }, 2500);
    window.line=document.getElementById('answer').value;

                {
                  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'qwe.php',
            data: {z: line},
            success: function(data) {

                $("q").text(data);

            }
        });
            document.getElementById('answer').reset();
                }
                 window.location.href=window.location.href;
}
```

i want to refresh after this function is executed. all the form values that i take in the html form should also be reset.

Comment: `location.href = location.href`

Comment: not working karthik

Comment: window.location.reload();

Comment: The least you can do when asking people for help is format your code readably and consistently. The above is an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 3):

`$.ajax()` returns results asynchronously. Move `window.location.href=window.location.href` to `success` function of `$.ajax()`. Remove two syntax errors `{` before `$.ajax()` call and `}` following `document.getElementById('answer').reset();`. Provide an identifier for `setTimeout`, and call `clearTimeout()` at `success`

Outside of `theFinale` function

```
var timeout = null;
```

```
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('pop4').className = 'waa';
}, 2500);

success: function(data) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            window.location.href=window.location.href;

         }
```

Comment: can i make it reload after a particular time?

Comment: @Rahul _"can i make it reload after a particular time?"_ Yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
           $("q").text(data);
           location.reload()
        }
```

Did you try this?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and mark as correct answer. Thanks!!